# Using a word to that makes something sound better than it is

Tags: meaning

What is the word that describes calling something by a banal title to disguise its true identity?  Such as hamburger which is actually ground up, bloody cow flesh.  Sounds nicer and doesn't remind people what they are actually eating.

Comment: If you're making hamburgers that turn out to be ground up bloody cow flesh, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I have to agree with @deadrat: a good steak taratre costs a hell of a lot more than a lousy hamburger. I'm not a fan. I'm just saying. Some people order riesling with it, but that's because they're morons. Red only goes with red.

Comment: **polite expression** comes to mind. Also, I found [this english.stackexchange question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22063/what-are-some-synonyms-for-euphemism), which suggests another great option: **paranym**.

Comment: Or maybe _groundupbloodycowfleshphobia_ would make a good generic name for the phenomenon.

Answer (score 4):

*euphemism*

> A euphemism is a generally innocuous word or expression used in place of one that may be found offensive or suggest something unpleasant.

Example:

[image: euphemisms]

> Sign in a Rite Aid drugstore using common American euphemisms for (from top): 
>   contraceptives, douches, tampons, and menstrual pads, respectively.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism))

Comment: +1 for the impatience. Euphemism isn't what the OP's looking for. It should be closer to name de plume, or working alias, or monicker, or something like that.

Comment: I think @Kyle's suggestion is in line with the OP's request: a word for a "banal" term for something more disturbing.  Of course, the OP actually asked for "the word that describes calling something" which technically would be more like the act of "euphemizing."

Comment: I agree with Kyle.  "Euphemism" is the banal title.  I also get where Kiri's going, but I'd say the adjective is "euphemistic"; the adverb, "euphemistically."